# Find the operator P(x,y,z)

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, orthogonality

I need some help with this problem.
$P:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ the linear operator such that $u=P(v)$ is the orthogonal projection of v E $\mathbb{R}^3$ on plane $3x+2y+z=0$. Find $P(x,y,z)$

(sorry for bad language, English isn't my main language)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. People will tend to downvote your question if you don't provide context and/or what you have tried, so try to add that if possible.

Comment: @N.Bar hi, thanks. Basically i dont even know how to start this exercise, but it is just what i wrote. No more information, just it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(3,2,1)$ is normal to the plane

$\frac {(x,y,z)\cdot(3,2,1)}{\|(3,2,1)\|}$ gives the distance of a point in space from the plane.

Then we move from this from this point in space, our distance, in the direction of the normal.

$(x,y,z) - \frac {(x,y,z)\cdot(3,2,1)}{\|(3,2,1)\|}\frac {(3,2,1)}{\|3,2,1\|}\\
(x,y,z) - \frac {(x,y,z)\cdot(3,2,1)}{\|(3,2,1)\|^2}(3,2,1)\\
(x,y,z) - \frac {3x + 2y + z}{14}(3,2,1)\\
(x,y,z) - (\frac {9x + 6y + 3z}{14}, \frac {6x + 4y + 2z}{14}, \frac {3x + 2y + 1z}{14})\\
(\frac {5x - 6y - 3z}{14}, \frac {-6x +10y - 2z}{14}, \frac {-3x - 2y + 13z}{14}) $

Comment: Just that solve the problem? It looks simple to do, if it is just it